# SQL - flag if a date falls within a date range within a select case statement?

Tags: sql, date, select, case

SQL-Any help is appreciated!

I would like to flag all rows in a dataset if the rows fall between the start of the previous month (01/07/2022) and todays date but last month (19/07/2022). I am hopefully looking to do a case statement so..

select
case when a.date between 01/07/2022 and 19/07/2022 then 1 else 0 end as Flag

from

dataset a

if there is any other optimal way of doing this without a case statement then that is perfect also

Table Format

| ID | DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/07/2022 |
| 2 | 08/07/2022 |
| 3 | 01/08/2022 |
| 4 | 05/08/2022 |

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

(I'm using ORACLE SQL, your dialect may vary :D))
How about

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN a.date >= to_date('20220701', 'YYYYMMDD') AND a.date <= to_date('20220719', 'YYYYMMDD') 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
       END as flag
FROM <tablename> a
```

[EDIT]
The only other way I could think of (moving the condition to two where clauses) looks ugly to me... :D:

```
with zeros as (
select a.date, 0 as flag
from <tablename> a
where NOT trade_date BETWEEN to_date('01/07/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND to_date('19/07/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
)
, ones as (
select a.date, 1 as flag
from <tablename> a
where trade_date BETWEEN to_date('01/07/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND to_date('19/07/2022', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
)
select date, flag from zeros
union
select date, flag from ones
order by date;
```

Comment: Thanks this would work in a 'where clause' but not in the select case part ...

Comment: What DBMS are you using? The statement definitely works in ORACLE SQL.

Comment: I am using SQL, I have put the table layout above also now-thanks

Comment: Maybe the alternative in my [edit] works?